# Process.Start fails with Path not found exception

Tags: c#, .net, process

Why the api Process.Start fails if it is called from a mapped drive. Steps to do create a project which calls `Process.Start()` on a simple exe. Map this folder as another drive letter access the same launching application via the mapped drive. When it is accessed via mapped drive it fails with an error message System can not find the path specified. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a program from a network (mapped) drive, it's run in a different security context (Intranet zone vs. local zone).  This changes the permissions, including the ability to potentially find the application.

Comment: True. And apparently this permission issue has changed with the new .NET 4.0 policies, which means we will be able to run .NET applications from a shared drive.

Comment: @Mike: That was changed with 3.5 SP1, there is no need to wait for 4.0.

Comment: Also, if you can't upgrade to 3.5SP1, you can use CASPOL.EXE utility (it's in the .net distribution folder) to change security policies. It's much easier though just to upgrade to SP1.